# Using compass in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, compass

I am trying to get compass to work in laravel 5.4, I have a existing project in laravel 5.4, I have upgraded to 5.4 and it no longer uses elixir. This is what i was using on 5.3 is there away i can still use compass so i dont have to start over again
in my 5.3 project

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-sass-compass');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.compass("resources/assets/sass/styles.scss", "public/css", {
        // style: "nested",
        sass: "resources/assets/sass",
        font: "resources/assets/fonts",
        image: "resources/assets/image",
        javascript: "resources/assets/scripts",
        sourcemap: true
    });
});
```

i have loads of scripts in compass and would like to stay using it if possible. Thanks

Comment: I see you've figured this out yourself already. One tip: Laravel Mix (formerly Laravel Elixir) ships with `autoprefixer` (https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) out of the box. I know this is one of the reasons why people use Compass. I recommend doing some research to try and see if you can replace your Compass calls with your own.

Comment: ok great i will look into that. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok i manged to fix this only took two days. first of all install compass mixings using `npm install mixin-loader --save-dev`

then in your app.scss add `@import "~compass-mixins/lib/compass";`

Then make sure you add `<link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">` to your

run `npm run watch`

this worked for me hope.

Comment: Hi, would love to add more details on how you solved it as I have the exact same problem. What should the `webpack.mix.js` file looks like?